# How to Get Xcom Values inside Kubernetes Pod Operator

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetespodoperator

Im Trying to pass a Xcom value as arguments inside a kubernetes pod operator But values are not populating.

Checked Xcom's List in Airflow UI I am able to see the key,value.

This is my syntax:

```
get_report_task = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="get_report_task",
    name="%s" % (DAG_ID.replace("_", "-")),
    namespace="dsm-kl",
    image=KUBER_IMAGE,
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    arguments=["{ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='{DAG_ID}', task_ids='push_task', key='kube_values')}"],
    labels={
        "vendor": "reversal",
        "job": "get_reports",
        "dag": DAG_ID,
        "task": "get_report_task",
        "task_id": "get_report_task",
    },
    retries=3,
    depends_on_past=False,
    dag=dag,
    resources={"request_memory": "512Mi", "limit_memory": "1024Mi"},
    affinity=DOC_AFFINITY,
)
```

Any Syntax Would be Helpful
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jinja template, you need to put the code between `{{<code>}}`, and you cannot use jinja in jija as you do to access dag id `{DAG_ID}`. When you want to read xcom from a task in the same dag, you don't need to provide the dag id:

```py
get_report_task = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="get_report_task",
    name="%s" % (DAG_ID.replace("_", "-")),
    namespace="dsm-kl",
    image=KUBER_IMAGE,
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    arguments=["{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task', key='kube_values')}}"],
    labels={
        "vendor": "reversal",
        "job": "get_reports",
        "dag": DAG_ID,
        "task": "get_report_task",
        "task_id": "get_report_task",
    },
    retries=3,
    depends_on_past=False,
    dag=dag,
    resources={"request_memory": "512Mi", "limit_memory": "1024Mi"},
    affinity=DOC_AFFINITY,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `arguments=[ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='DAG_ID', task_ids='push_task', key='kube_values')]`?

Comment: I tried. It throws error stating: ti not defined. @Andres Traumann